# Statistical Inference: Casella Berger - PDF of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have been going through Casella Berger recently, and I am not sure I understand this concept. I get that one needs to split the intervals so that the function X^2 is monotone, but why cannot the intervals be (-1,0), {0}, (0,2)? I have seen this question asked here before, but I still do not understand the explanation.

The question

[image]

Merry christmas to those who celebrate, and happy holidays regardless.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I apologize; Will do next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that $X-\text{support}$ is not symmetric. If you do a drawing of the transformation function $Y=X^2$ you see that in the interval $[1;2]$ the transformation function is monotonic thus you can apply directly the theorem.  In the interval $[-1;1]$ you must use the definition of CDF

Anyway you can use the intervals $[-1;0]$ and $[0;2]$. The result will be the same.  But you have to pay attention because in $[-1;0]$ and $[0;1]$ $Y-\text{support}$ is the same and thus you should divide the support in 3 intervals to apply the theorem. The proposed solution is the most suitable

---

I am not at home and I have not my Casella Berger with me but I think the theorem they refer to is

$$f_Y(y)=f_X[g^{-1}(y)]\Bigg|\frac{d}{dy}g^{-1}(y)\Bigg|$$

Comment: Yes, that is the one. Thank you for the detailed response.